# Is there non-english syntax of c++

Tags: c++

I heard that there is a non-english syntax of c++, it seems to be as c++ style but with translated terms!
can we find a lang like this!

Comment: If it exists its creator should be shot.

Comment: Anyone with good enough English to propose it doesn't need it, so the committee never gets a chance to consider it ;-)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English-based_programming_languages

Comment: I've seen German versions using `wenn`, `ja` and `nein`.

Comment: Programming in Klingon: http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Lingua-tlhInganHol-yIghun-20090601/lib/Lingua/tlhInganHol/yIghun.pm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
#define пока while
#define типа virtual
#define дай new
#define нах delete
...
#define бюст boost
```

Comment: Does Russian (is this Russian?) have gendered adjectives, should there be more than one variant of `new` to match the gender of the class name?

Comment: @Steve Thats true. but i resolved that problem by saying `gimme` instead of `new`

Answer (score 6):

I guess that you might be able to pull something like that with a preprocessor, but I would greatly advice against this approach. Programming languages are not English or Spanish or any other natural language, but rather a set of keywords with *precise* meanings in that language.

If you decide to *translate* the language, you would end up with a situation where either the compiler errors are completely alien to your code (if the language is pre translated before passing to the compiler) or in the best case with compiler support and error messages that you cannot use to ask for help in forums like StackOverflow.

This second approach has been taken in some cases (VBA, as the first example that comes to mind), and the result is a language that is still not natural to the native speakers and for which the available information is fragmented into the different languages. As a matter of fact, that already happens with current C++ compilers... I have disabled localization of the compiler for a long time on that grounds.

Comment: yeah, and for vba, there are conflicts with variable names. Those damn guys did even localize the floating point separators and mathematical functions. The result is that when you have a french spreadsheet, you cannot read it with an english excel. As a result, we (I'm in france) use all programs exclusively in english, although there is a huge amount of money spent (wasted) to translate every tiny bit of Office into many languages.

Comment: AFAIK Excel doesn't localize its fp seperators; it picks them up from the OS localization setting. English versions can pick up `,` and French versions can pick up `.`. But macro names are a true horror. Shooting the person responsible is too good.

Answer (score 0):

[Sí](https://akercheval.github.io/si/); it lets you write code with Spanish keywords and then translate it into C++ or Python.